# Linq to sql datetime issue

Tags: c#

When I am calling  GetClosestStartDate it is popingup the following message Additional information:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String
>   ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store
>   expression.
>   I also tried by removing ToString from "TT.Startdate.Value.ToString()" and Changing "string CStartdate { get; set; } to DateTime CStartdate { get; set; }"

```
class Class_CourseStartdate
{
    public string CStartdate { get; set; }
    public int TimeTableID { get; set; }
}

   public List<Class_CourseStartdate> GetClosestStartDate(DateTime CoeStartdate)
   {
       return (from TT in _er.TimeTables
               where TT.Startdate == CoeStartdate
               select new Class_CourseStartdate 
               { CStartdate = TT.Startdate.Value.ToString() ,
                 TimeTableID = TT.TimeTableID 
               }
               ).ToList();
   }
```

Comment: Why is `CStartdate` a `string`?

Comment: Basically you can remove .ToString() from linq. Change you property type as datetime in your class. And convert your datetime object to string where you use it.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach is to fetch just the data you want in the part that's translated into SQL, and then do the rest locally:

```
public List<Class_CourseStartdate> GetClosestStartDate(DateTime coeStartdate)
{
    return _er.TimeTables
              .Where(tt => tt.Startdate == coeStartdate)
              .Select(tt => new { tt.Startdate, tt.TimeTableID })
              .AsEnumerable() // Do the rest locally
              .Select(tt => new Class_CourseStartdate 
              { 
                   CStartdate = tt.Startdate.Value.ToString() ,
                   TimeTableID = tt.TimeTableID 
              }
              .ToList();
}
```

Note that I've stopped using a query expression here, as it becomes ugly when you need to then call methods on it - and all you're doing is a simple `Where` and `Select`. Query expressions are most useful when they involve transparent identifiers, e.g. in joins.

Next up, I would notice that we're already checking that `tt.Startdate` is equal to the date we've passed in - so why bother fetching it?

```
public List<Class_CourseStartdate> GetClosestStartDate(DateTime coeStartdate)
{
    return _er.TimeTables
              .Where(tt => tt.Startdate == coeStartdate)
              .Select(tt => tt.TimeTableID)
              .AsEnumerable() // Do the rest locally
              .Select(tid => new Class_CourseStartdate 
              { 
                   CStartdate = coeStartDate.ToString() ,
                   TimeTableID = tid
              }
              .ToList();
}
```

Or possibly just change the method to return timetable IDs, given that that's *really* what it's doing. I'd change the method name too:

```
public List<int> GetTimeTableIdsForStartDate(DateTime coeStartdate)
{
    return _er.TimeTables
              .Where(tt => tt.Startdate == coeStartdate)
              .Select(tt => tt.TimeTableID)
              .ToList();
}
```

Even if you *do* stick with `Class_CourseStartdate` I would change the `CStartdate` property to be just `DateTime` rather than `string` - avoid using strings in your models unless you *really, really* have to.

Additionally, your naming currently feels like it's all over the place - `Startdate` should be `StartDate` everywhere, you should drop the `C` and `Class_` prefixes, etc.

Comment: +1 Since yours is now the earliest answer using `IQueryable.AsEnumerable` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Jodrell: It's actually `Enumerable.AsEnumerable`, but hey :)

Comment: @user3513192, I whole heartedly agree with the comments on naming and class design.

Comment: @Jodrell: Yup, from my obviously-biased perspective, that's a much better reason for upvoting my answer than just timing ;)

Comment: I was trying to distinguish from `DataTableExtensions.AsEnumerable()` which obviously doesn't apply here My mistake has lead to greater insight.

Comment: @JonSkeet - shouldn't the IDs function return List<int> ?

Comment: @NDJ: Yup - I hadn't spotted that we actually knew the `TimeTableID` type.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
return (from TT in _er.TimeTables
        where TT.Startdate == CoeStartdate
        select new  
        {
            CStartdate = TT.Startdate.Value.ToString() ,
            TimeTableID = TT.TimeTableID 
        }
        ).AsEnumerable()
         .Select(x=> new Class_CourseStartdate
         {
             CStartdate = x.CStartdate.Value.ToString(),
             TimeTableID = x.TimeTableID
         }).ToLIst();
```

This way you fecth the data from the database and then you apply the formatting you want.

Comment: change it back to `AsEnumerable` quick

Answer (score 0):

Most functions that are not in defined in `LINQ` namespace can not be used inside `LINQ` expressions for `IQueryabe` (`ToString` being one of those). The solution is to just copy the value as it is and perform the conversion afterwards, or replace the `LINQ` with a `for` loop to iterate through the values, in which case you can use your `ToString` correctly.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have a possible exception there: `TT.StartDate` may be null and when calling `Value` you'll get an exception.

Second of all, why is `CStartDate` a string? You won't be able to perform `DateTime` specific operations with it and you may encounter problems when converting a string back to `DateTime` if the conversion is made on a thread with different culture.

As a quick fix, you can try adding a second projection to your query, after loading data in memory:

```
return _er.TimeTables
    .Where(tt => tt.Startdate == CoeStartdate)
    .Select(tt => new { StartDate = tt.StartDate, Id = tt.TimeTableID})
    .ToList()
    .Select(tt => new Class_CourseStartDate
    {
        // Avoid the exception by checking if property has value
        CStartDate = tt.StartDate.HasValue ? tt.StartDate.Value.ToString() : String.Empty,
        TimeTableId = tt.Id
    })
    .ToList();
```